# Example of compact Riemannian manifold with only one closed geodesic.

Tags: differential-geometry, examples-counterexamples, geodesic

The [Lyusternik-Fet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyusternik%E2%80%93Fet_theorem) states that every compact Riemannian manifold has at least one closed geodesic.

Are there any easy-to-construct<sup>1</sup> examples of compact Riemannian manifolds for which it is easy to see they only have one closed geodesic?<sup>2</sup>

If there aren't any such examples, are there any easy-to-construct examples that only have one closed geodesic but where proving this might be difficult?

And if there aren't any examples of *this*, are there any examples at all of compact manifolds with only one closed geodesic?

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, the $1$-sphere $S^1$ contains just one closed geodesic, but I'm interested in examples besides this one.

<sup>2</sup> By the [theorem of the three geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem_of_the_three_geodesics), this example cannot be a topological sphere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you have to exclude constant maps $S^1\to M$ from consideration: They are all closed geodesics. Secondly, you have to talk about **geometrically distinct** closed geodesics: Geodesics which have the same image are regarded as "the same". Then, it is a notorious conjecture/open problem:

Conjecture. Every compact Riemannian manifold of dimension $n >1$ contains infinitely many geometrically distinct nonconstant geodesics.

See for instance [this survey article](https://aimath.org/pastworkshops/geodesicsproblems.pdf) by Burns and Matveev.

This is known for surfaces (with the only hard case when the surface is diffeomorphic to $S^2$ in which case the result is due to Bangert and Franks) and for many higher-dimensional manifolds. However, the problem is open already when $M$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere $S^n$, $n\ge 3$.

**Edit.** I recently found a preprint which claims to prove the conjecture on closed geodesics:

S. Charles, [The Existence of Infinitely Many Geometrically Distinct Non-constant Prime Closed Geodesics on Riemannian Manifolds](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.04017.pdf), 2018.

The paper is still unpublished and I do not know if the proof is correct.

Answer (score 7):

If you analyze the geodesics using [Clairaut's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation), you'll find that the only closed geodesic on a hyperboloid of one sheet is the central circle. Indeed, the same holds for a concave surface of revolution of the same "shape" as the hyperboloid of one sheet.

**EDIT**: Apologies for missing the crucial compactness hypothesis.

Comment: Lovely example, but a hyperboloid isn't compact, right?

Comment: Oops. Sloppy reading. I'll delete.

Comment: It's a nice example; you should leave it.